# Azure search - Provide scoring profile in search query

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am new to azure search. May be I am not googling properly, but can anyone guide how can scoring profile be made as part of search query?

Or how can a field (lets say **Title** among fields like **Id, Address, Title**) be given a higher weight, so that if the searched text matches some **Title**, then it is given a higher score, as compared to when searched text matches **Address**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create a scoring profile with the field weights that you want, and either indicate you want to use it in each search request (using the "scoringProfile" query parameter), or mark it as default to get it automatically applied.

The details on how to author a scoring profile are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index

Comment: Is there a way that I can assign relative weights to fields? Like assign **Title** twice the weight assigned to **Address**.

Comment: Yes, that's part of the scoring profile definition, it's described in the link I included in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out "mark it as default to get it automatically applied". Otherwise you'll be left scratching your head wondering why the profile's not working.